# get value from array in php

Tags: php, syntax

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [OPT] => 65 ) )
```

how to get `65` to a variable in PHP

help me please....

Comment: try to use quotes for array keys otherwise they are interpreted as constants

Answer (score 5):

In all simplicity:

```
$foo = array(array('opt'=>65));
$bar = $foo[0]['OPT'];
```

I suggest you familiarize yourself with [the basics of PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.php) and the excellent [language reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/langref.php) provided by PHP.net.

Answer (score 3):

```
$variable = $arrayname[0]['OPT'];
```

there are plenty of [useful information for the beginners in the official manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

Answer (score 2):

```
$arr = array(array('OPT'=>65)); // the array
echo $arr[0]['OPT'];            // will print 65
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$var=$arr[0]['OPT'];
```

To know more about array [see](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) this

Answer (score 0):

To prevent warnings, get value only if $arrayname[0]['OPT'] exists. If not - $variable will store default value - 0.

```
$variable = isset($arrayname[0]['OPT'])?$arrayname[0]['OPT']:0;
```

Comment: Suggesting an inline conditional to someone who doesn't know how to reference an array value?  This is a little brutal.

Comment: I dont think so. I also started with simple questions and learned many new things along the way

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php 

$test= array ('0' => Array ( 'OPT' => 65 ) );
foreach($test as $val1) {
   foreach($val1 as $val2) {
       echo $val2;
       }
    }
?>
```